# Wordpress Custom post type with pagination (metakey with price)

Tags: wordpress

when i add below meta between query in code i will not working

```
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => array($min_price, $max_price),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
```

**How can i add meta query in below query.**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$data = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product', // your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // post per page
    'paged' => $paged,
));?>
```

Please check code

Answer (score 0):

Please find following code

```
$data = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product', // your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // post per page
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => array($min_price, $max_price),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
));
```